# Adding a column based on a list dplyr

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to summarise a list of dataframes. Here is some test data

```
noms <- list('A', 'B')

A_data <- data.frame('Dis' = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                     'adj' = c(3, 2, 6, 7))
B_data <- data.frame('Dis' = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                     'adj' = c(2, 6, 3, 6))

frames <- list(A_data, B_data)
```

I want to produce a list of data frams where'adj' is summed for each 'Dis' group, and then add a column for the relevant name from 'noms' so I can then combine the data frames together to form a single dataframe in the future.

So far I have this:

```
totals <- setNames(lapply(frames, function (x)
  x %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Dis) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(total = sum(adj)))
  ,paste0(unlist(noms)))
```

But I can figure out how to add a column with the relevant name. I know I need to use the `mutate` function something like so:

```
totals <- setNames(lapply(frames, function (x)
  x %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Dis) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(total = sum(adj)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(nom = )
  ,paste0(unlist(noms)))
```

but I cant figure out how to add the correct name.

The expected output would be a list of two dataframes one for 'A' and one for 'B'. Here is the expected output for 'A':

```
    Dis total Nom
1     1     5   A
2     2    13   A
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R option where we use `Map` instead of `lapply`

```
out <- Map(function(x, y) {
  transform(aggregate(adj ~ Dis, data = x, sum), Nom = y)
}, x = frames, y = noms)
out
#[[1]]
#  Dis adj Nom
#1   1   5   A
#2   2  13   A

#[[2]]
#  Dis adj Nom
#1   1   8   B
#2   2   9   B
```

---

The same idea with `tidyverse` functions

```
library(purrr); library(dplyr)
map2(.x = frames, .y = noms, ~ .x %>% 
       group_by(Dis) %>% 
       summarise(adj = sum(adj)) %>% 
       mutate(Nom = .y))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you. Is there any benefit to one over the other?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, I'd prefer the base R option because you don't need any external packages but I don't see any other benefits here.